# Saving email attachments with Outlook / Exchange when offline

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I can save attachments from Outlook automatically using VBA and inbox rules.  The problem with this is that I need to be logged in.

Is there any way to save attachments while my machine is turned off?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you have a cached profile, all the data is stored in an OST file, and your machine can be offline, but your code can still access the cached messages and attachments.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended my question to clarify - apologies for the confusion

Comment: If you machine is off, how can the folder be accessed?

Comment: If it is a network folder that I want to save to, is there any way to do this from a server?  Presumably not using vba

Comment: No, Exchange server side rule will not do anything file based.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your replies. I was wondering whether you could set a rule up via webmail to run some sort of script. Is there any other way to achieve this or create a workaround? Running a script from my machine works fine until I am on holiday...

Comment: No, Exchange will not run any scripts either - think about it, that would be a huge security hole.